# add record if id is not known else update the record

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have the following table in mariadb:

-id = key which shall autoincrement
-price
-amount
-name
-order_id

order_id can appear twice in the table but the combination of name and order_id should be unique. I now have a combination of name and order_id.

What I want to do is to add a record if the combination of name and order_id is not in the table.
If it's in then I want to change/get the amount value.

Is there a nice query to accomplish this?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like using `on duplicate key update` for this.  You need to start by creating a unique index on `name` and `order_id`:

```
create unique index ix_table_orderid_name on table(order_id, name);
```

Then the `insert` looks like:

```
insert into table(price, amount, name, order_id)
    values (@price, @amount, @name, @order_id)
    on duplicate key update amount = values(amount), price = values(price);
```

This replaces the values in the table with the new values.  You can also increment them.  Your question is unclear on the exact operation.